# C++ what parts of a function declaration line goes in the first line of the definition?

Tags: c++, function

I've never been clear on exactly how much of the declaration line (typically placed in the header file) makes it into the first line of the function definition. Some keywords cause compilation to fail if they're repeated in the definition, some don't.

As an example, consider an exception class inherited from `std::exception`. The redefinition of the `what()` function typically looks like

```
virtual const char* what() const throw();
```

Okay, fine. If I define this in a source file, and I copy over this line exactly

```
virtual const char* what() const throw() {}
```

compilation fails with a message like "virtual outside class declaration". I delete "virtual" and it compiles fine. What are the rules for what parts of the function declaration need to be repeated in in its definition? Static? Inline? Is there a reference that describes concisely which parts are necessary?

Comment: The problem is not the specifiers, but that you are not defining a class method (the name is not e.g. `std::exception::what`). As for what is and is not necessary, someone will quote the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very good explanation of what goes into declaration and what goes into definition:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fash2fc6.aspx - declaration syntax
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4d5ssht.aspx - definition syntax